# Change post title if post has specific category

Tags: categories, filters, get-the-title

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to have title changed of posts which are in category number 30.

My code is:

```
function adddd($title) {

if(has_category('30',$post->ID)){
$title = 'Prefix '.$title;
}

return $title;
}
add_action('the_title','adddd');
```

The code works, but has one issue. When I am inside the post which has that category, title is being changed for all other pages (which are called through the_title) too.

How can I change the title only to post titles which has that category, no matter what page I am on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$post` is undefined in your filter. You need to explicitely invoke the `$post` global inside your filter function to have it available. You must remember that variables (*even global variables*) outside a function will not be available inside a function, that is how PHP works.

You actually do not need to use the `$post` global, the post ID is passed by reference as second parameter to the `the_title` filter.

You can use the following:

```
add_action( 'the_title', 'adddd', 10, 2 );
function adddd( $title, $post_id ) 
{
    if( has_category( 30, $post_id ) ) {
        $title = 'Prefix ' . $title;
    }

    return $title;
}
```

If you need to target only the titles of posts in the main query/loop, you can wrap your contional in an extra `in_the_loop()` condition

Answer (score 0):

Why not use javascript/jquery?

if your use `<?php post_class(); ?>` you can find a different class for each category.

```
    $('.post.category-one').find('h2.item-title').prepend('Prefix ');
```

Use `.find()` to the selector title

### Edit

With php try this

```
function adddd($title) {
    global $post;

    if(has_category('30',$post->ID)) {
        $title = 'Prefix '.$post->post_title;
    }

    return $title;
}
add_action('the_title','adddd');
```

Comment: I want to achieve this with php, because I will use it for another scripts, where js won't help. Thanks anyway

Comment: @Simon I updated my answer